# Using SSH ForwardAgent and ProxyJump with IdentityFile in command line

Tags: linux, command-line, ssh, proxy

I am using the new ProxyJump option with SSH. I am having troubles with the IdentityFile for the proxy.

Sample SSH config:

```
Host proxy
     HostName 1.0.0.1
     User foo
     Port 1234
     Identityfile ~/.ssh/mykey.id_rsa

Host target
     HostName 1.0.1.1
     User bar
     Port 5678
     Identityfile ~/.ssh/mykey.id_rsa
     ProxyJump proxy
     ForwardAgent yes
```

Schematic:

```
            ssh          ssh
localhost ------> proxy ------> target
             ^             ^
           using         using
           mykey         mykey
```

Using the ssh command with this config works out:

```
ssh target
```

I am trying to perform this operation without the config file, but it does not work:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/mykey.id_rsa -AJ foo@1.0.0.1:1234 bar@1.0.1.1:5678
```

I can't find a way to specify the IdentityFile with `-i` for both the ProxyJump host and the target host to make it work.

This works:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/mykey.id_rsa -AJ proxy bar@1.0.1.1:5678
```

Is there a way of using the `-i`,`-A`,`-J` or `-o` flags to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do that with the new jump magic as far as I know. But it should work with the "old" proxy-command:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/mykey.id_rsa -Ao ProxyCommand="ssh -i ~/.ssh/mykey.id_rsa -W %h:%p -p 1234 foo@1.0.0.1" -p 5678 bar@1.0.1.1
```

Comment: getting error: 'SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6\r': command not found'

Comment: @dhroove doing something wrong.

Comment: ssh -ti privatekey.pem -Ao ProxyCommand="ssh -i privatekey.pem user@hostname" user@hostname -> where privatekey.pem is the key file

Comment: added all details: https://superuser.com/questions/1344557/ssh-through-jump-sever-using-private-key-in-macbook

Comment: It's a shame, I will like to use the `ssh -j` command specifying an ssh key.