# SSH through jump sever using private key (in macbook)

Tags: mac, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I am trying to do SSH where target server is accessible through jump server only.

```
 +-------+       +----------+      +--------------+
 | Laptop| <---> | Jumphost | <--> | TargetServer |
 +-------+       +----------+      +--------------+
```

To access the server, I have to use my private key.

I recently shifted to MAC from Windows machine. 
In windows I was using WINSCP tool and through **tunnel** option in WINSCP and **Allowing agent forwarding** I was able to access the target servers.

Target server setting:
[image]

Tunnel setting:
[image]

Authentication/Agent forwarding setting
[image]

I have placed same private key in both the settings.

Now I am looking for direct SSH command (to execute on MAC) so that I can access servers.

I have tried the following command

```
ssh -i privatekey.pem -Ao ProxyCommand="ssh -i privatekey.pem user@jumpserver" user@targethostname
```

but getting an error:

-bash: line 1: $'SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6\r': command not found

Comment: You probably have some alias defined, that expands some of your constants to something you don't want. What is output of `alias`? Write `set -x`, press enter and write your command again. What is the output?

Answer (score 2):

Following command worked for me

```
ssh -i privatekey.pem -o "ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p -i privatekey.pem user@jumpserverhost" user@targetserver
```

Comment: Welcome to superuser: While this may or may not answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some more explanation why your solution works with detail and easy to follow instructions so that the readers who do not understand code as well as others can use the answer as well. If you feel your answer is correct and fix's the problem then re-edit it. Please take a couple of minutes and read:- .Answering: [help], [answer], again welcome to superuser and keep answering. Thankyou